# Avoid infinite loop on React - useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-tsx

How do I put a function (that is on a context) that is exported and also receives a parameter inside a useEffect so the setState inside that function doesn't cause infinite re-renders.

function:

```
export const PokemonProvider = ({children} : {children: ReactNode}) => {
    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useLocalStorage<Pokemon[]>('pokemon', [{id: 123, name: 'mariomon', type: 'fogo', imageUrl: 'www.google.com'}]);

    const getPokemon = (newlyPokemon : Pokemon | null) => {
        newlyPokemon && setPokemon(prevState => [...prevState, newlyPokemon]);
    };

    return <PokemonContext.Provider value={{getPokemon, pokemon}}>
        {children}
    </PokemonContext.Provider>
}
```

getPokemon might be the issue here and even though my knowledge on React is limited how do I access newlyPokemon if I use a useCallback e.g? should I use a useRef and assign it the newlyPokemon value on getPokemon and then setPokemon inside a useEffect?

help needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useCallback` doesn't care how many parameters your callback has, since that doesn't change the location of where the function is stored.

There is no `useEffect` in the code provided.

If the `useLocalStorage` hook is written in the correct way, its setter function should already be wrapped in a `useCallback` so its memory location shouldn't ever change.

When you wrap your `getPokemon` in `useCallback`, its only dependency is `setPokemon`.

```
const getPokemon = useCallback((newlyPokemon : Pokemon | null) => {
  newlyPokemon && setPokemon(prevState => [...prevState, newlyPokemon]);
}, [setPokemon]);
```

If you're worried about rerenders, look into a state manager to control which elements get rerendered since any change to `pokemon` will cause every child of the `PokemonProvider` to rerender